# Book about miniaturized robots that you could control, similar to the neck port in The Matrix

Tags: story-identification

The book was about miniaturization of robots. The story follows two friends
who, through the use of something quite similar to the Matrix movies’ “neck
port”, could port into small (~1″ tall) robots. The story starts with a
focus around the main characters backyard, in which, porting into the
robots, the friends play around, have fun, slaying insects and such. Also,
within the first few pages of the book there is an assassination. Which is the
“bad guy” using a tiny robot to kill a man while he is driving, the report
says that he simply had a “car accident”, though.

The “miniature” robots is a relatively new discovery in the world of
science and the only reason the boys have access to it is because the one
(who's house the story happens) is the son of the creator.

Early in the book, a person is being given a tour of the facilities where
these robots are created and he is shown an area in which people who
control micro-sized robots are building things.

As for title or Author, I have no clue, except that I think that " ______'s
Backyard" may have been the title. Time frame for publication would be
Pre-2000.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Bug Park](http://www.baenebooks.com/p-52-bug-park.aspx) by James P. Hogan

> Kevin Heber had it good. He had his own lab, a colleague he could
>   trust, and an idea that could make him millions. Using his father's
>   breakthrough technology in direct neural interfacing, he and his
>   friend Taki have created a new entertainment media—live action
>   adventure in micro mechanical scale. Bug Park: The ultimate out of
>   body experience. And Taki's uncle wants to take it public.
>
> Two problems:
>
> 1-Kevin and Taki are teenagers.
>
> 2-Somebody wants to squash Bug Park dead, and Kevin's father along
>   with it.
>
> When you're a teenager, even a teenager with a rich, indulgent parent,
>   you don't have a lot of power. But when things get very small, the
>   rules change. Physics changes. What every body knows, ain't so, the
>   weak are mighty, and the mighty and the powerful can be brought down
>   by those they thought they've already trodden underfoot. And even
>   those who think they own the world can learn the hard way that
>   innocence is not another word for "stupid,"